# C++ Accessing other instances' data in OOP

Tags: c++, class, oop, instance

I have a problem in my OOP homework. I have to code a 1 v 1 battle that takes these things to account:

Turn order, hit rate, and damage bonuses.

All these three rely on the stats of the attacker and defender.

My problem is, how can I access the data from the other instance of the same class? Since I have a function `opponentSpawner()` that creates another instance of my Unit class.

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my Header file (Unit.h):

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Unit
{
public:
    // Constructor and Destructor
    Unit();
    ~Unit();

    // Getters
    std::string getName();
    std::string getCharClass();
    int getHp();
    int getPow();
    int getVit();
    int getAgi();
    int getDex();

    // Basic functions
    void createCharacter();
    void createOpponent();
    void printStats();
    int attack();
    int checkClass();

private:
    std::string mName;
    std::string mCharClass;
    int mHp;
    int mPow;
    int mVit;
    int mAgi;
    int mDex;

};
```

And here's my .cpp file (Unit.cpp):

```
#include "Unit.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

Unit::Unit()
{
}

Unit::~Unit()
{
}

std::string Unit::getName()
{
    return mName;
}

std::string Unit::getCharClass()
{
    return mCharClass;
}

int Unit::getHp()
{
    return mHp;
}

int Unit::getPow()
{
    return mPow;
}

int Unit::getVit()
{
    return mVit;
}

int Unit::getAgi()
{
    return mAgi;
}

int Unit::getDex()
{
    return mDex;
}

void Unit::createCharacter()
{
    int choice;
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "[1] Warrior" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[2] Assassin" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[3] Mage" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Select your class: ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        mName = name;
        mCharClass = "Warrior";
        mHp = 20;
        mPow = 10;
        mVit = 10;
        mAgi = 5;
        mDex = 5;

    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        mName = name;
        mCharClass = "Assassin";
        mHp = 15;
        mPow = 5;
        mVit = 5;
        mAgi = 10;
        mDex = 15;

    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        mName = name;
        mCharClass = "Mage";
        mHp = 10;
        mPow = 15;
        mVit = 5;
        mAgi = 10;
        mDex = 10;

    }
    system("cls");
}

void Unit::createOpponent()
{
    srand(unsigned int(time(0)));
    int choice = (1 + rand() % 3);
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        mName = "Enemy Warrior";
        mCharClass = "Warrior";
        mHp = 20;
        mPow = 10;
        mVit = 10;
        mAgi = 5;
        mDex = 5;
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        mName = "Enemy Assassin";
        mCharClass = "Assassin";
        mHp = 15;
        mPow = 5;
        mVit = 5;
        mAgi = 10;
        mDex = 15;
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        mName = "Enemy Mage";
        mCharClass = "Mage";
        mHp = 10;
        mPow = 15;
        mVit = 5;
        mAgi = 10;
        mDex = 10;
    }
}

void Unit::printStats()
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Class: " << getCharClass() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "HP: " << getHp() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "POW: " << getPow() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "VIT: " << getVit() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "AGI: " << getAgi() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "DEX: " << getDex() << std::endl;

}

int Unit::attack()
{
    int damage = (this->getPow() - getVit());

    if (checkClass() == 1)
    {
        damage * 1.5;
        return damage;
    }
    if (checkClass() == 2)
    {
        damage * .5;
        return damage;
    }
    if (checkClass() == 3)
    {
        return damage;
    }
}

int Unit::checkClass()
{
    if (getCharClass() == "Warrior")
    {
        if ()
    }

}
```

And here is my main.cpp:

```
#include "Unit.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void opponentSpawner();

int main()
{

    Unit* unit1 = new Unit();
    unit1->createCharacter();
    unit1->printStats();
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    opponentSpawner();
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void opponentSpawner()
{
    // Flavor texts
    std::cout << "An enemy is approaching the Arena!" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    Unit* unit2 = new Unit();
    unit2->createOpponent();
    unit2->printStats();

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to access data from another instance? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @developerbmw There are functions that needs the stat of the opponents that I fight in the program. So I was wondering how can I access their stats in order to complete the function `attack()` and `checkClass()`?

Comment: Stop using new - there's no need to risk memory leaks here. Your units have getters, can't you call them? Only call `srand` **once** per program.

Comment: why do want another instance here. You can pass the first instance to `opponentSpawner` using `void opponentSpawner(Unit*);`

Comment: @NeilKirk yes, I think I shouldn't use new as well, but our professor specifically asked us to use it. About the `srand`, I will place it on the main cpp at the first line after `int main()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the instance from the method argument if you want to access the first instance in your opponentSpawner..

i.e..

```
void opponentSpawner(Unit* u);
```

OR

If you want to access the instance you created in opponentSpawner outside in the main.

you can use

```
 Unit* opponentSpawner();
```

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot! I will try to incorporate that to my work. I'll report in updates.

Comment: @AlfredIntal, if this solves your problem, it would be great if you mark this as correct.